# How to Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 to enable only TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 in Apache for a Wordpress Bitnami Amazon-Ligthsail instance?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

This is my first experience with Amazon Lighsail, Wordpress Multisite, Bitnami 
and even with Let's Encrypt; now it seems everything just works, except for SSL directives in my virtualhost file.

Because it seems that major browsers – aka Chrome, Safari/Webkit, Mozilla Firefox and IE/Edge - are going to remove support to TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, as soon as the beginning of the new year – precisely among January and March – I would want to know how to disable them for my new Wordpress Multisite instance in Lightsail.

After I obtained a Let’s Encript SSL certificate and successfully deployed it I tested it to verify that TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are enabled along with TLS 1.2. 
Now it seems that my Apache version 2.4.39 supports also TLS 1.3 and I am trying to enable even it and disable the two older versions. 
Reading on the net I found that I must change the httpd.conf file to insert this directive

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

so, inside the httpd.conf file I found this block, that seems the right place:

```
# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA$
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/mydomain.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/mydomain.key"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I tryed to simply update the httpd.conf and the httpd-ssl.conf, but nothing appens: TLS 1.3 does not work and TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are always anabled.

Now, and I read even this question

[Disabling TLS 1.0 in Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437546/disabling-tls-1-0-in-apache-2-4][1])

after my adds, this is my ssl directives in httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
# SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProtocol  +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
#SSLProtocol all -TLSv1 -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

But nothing changed and now I really do not know how to enable TLS 1.3 and disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.
Of course after every change I used to restart Apache.

Comment: After all yersterday I found another configuration file and now TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 are disabled. But it seems it is not possible to enable even the TLSv1.3:           
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.3' is the msg I received! Someone can help me?

Comment: Verify your logs at startup and confirm which version you are running.  `+TLSv3` did not exist before 2.4.  Or if you have access to run it, do `apachectl -v`.

Comment: apachectl -v returns "Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)"                     
That's why I expected be able to enable TLSv1.3

Comment: Furthermore error_log file reports this ssl:warn:                                              
this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this problem and put together the following solution:

1. Open an instance of SSH from your Lightsail dashboard
2. Navigate to: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/
3. Add the following line to the bitnami.conf file under where it says:

Listen 443
.#SSLProtocol -SSLv2 -SSLv3

> SSLProtocol TLSv1.2

4. Navigate to: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra
5. In the httpd-ssl.conf file, add the hashtag to the following lines (without the . ):

> .#SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
>   .#SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES

Now remove the hastag from the following lines so they read as:

> SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA
>   SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA

6. Now under #SSL Protocol Support, change the settings to look like this:

> .#SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
>   SSLProtocol -TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.3 -SSLv3
>   .#SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
>   SSLProxyProtocol -TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.3 -SSLv3

Reboot apache with: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Check your site at both:
https://www.whynopadlock.com
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

You should now receive and A score and no TLS 1.0 amd TLS 1.1 protocols being supported.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not yet possible to enable TLSv1.3. 
According to this bitnami's community thread:

[ https://community.bitnami.com/t/tlsv1-3-support-for-new-lamp-stack-installers/67672 ]

> TLSv1.3 is only supported with Apache version 2.4.36 and OpenSSL 1.1.1...our stacks include OpenSSL 1.0.2 so it's not currently possible to enable that protocol. Sorry for the inco…

Waiting for updates...

Comment: The wait did not last long; Bitnami just updated the stack, with Apache 2.4.41 along with OpenSSL 1.1.1d. TLSv1.3, fully enabled, alongside TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is behind Cloudflare or a similar service, then you will need to make the TLS changes on Cloudflare itself, regardless of whether you have set up the `SSLProtocol` correctly in `bitnami.conf`.